# Is it possible to acheive a band pass filter with a pass bandwidth sufficient to discriminate AM radio channels, without using an inductor?

Tags: filter, band-pass

I am wondering if it is possible to make a filter circuit that has a high enough Q/small enough pass bandwidth to discriminate AM channels, which are spaced 10 kHz apart in the ~1000kHz range - so with a pass band bandwidth of <1% of the center frequency - without using an inductor?

I will also note that my goal is not to use such a filter for actually filtering AM radio signals. I am trying to filter non-radio voltage signals at ~1kHz and hoping to be able to achieve similar discrimination as a radio tuner (pass bandwidth ~10Hz), hopefully without using an inductor.

Based on my investigation of high Q active band pass filters, even a [6th order filter](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiducc9a/tiducc9a.pdf) seems to have a roughly 10x larger pass bandwidth than what I am looking for.

If this is possible without using dozens of op amps, what is the simplest way to achieve it?

Comment: Define fo (IF=455kHz), BW and band stop BW @ -xdB then passband ripple dB and estimate GBW from fo x Q^2 x Av

Comment: Sounds to me like a job for a micro and some simple DSP...

Comment: Have you heard of SAW filters?

Comment: Or a crystal filter?

Comment: The question "inductor yes/no" has nothing to do with your question. Of course, you can realize active bandpass filters with a Q of 100 - and if you like with an opamp-based  "virtual inductor" .

Comment: Yes it is. A crystal filter is actually too selective. (But if you're looking at active filters, look at twin-T filters in the Q-multiplier configuration. Noise performance will be vastly inferior to L-C filters but it's your choice to avoid them) But at LF, @brhans is right. Digitise it and use DSP.

Comment: The only solutions that I know for Q=100 @ 1MHz in h/w is a SAW filter or ceramic resonator at std. or custom order characteristics as the GBW must be 10GHz for an amplifier to have 0 phase shift at 1 MHz in the feedback loop due to the Amp response